# Disable power saver mode using Android Management API policy

Tags: android, android-management-api, android-doze

In the Android Management API policy, is there any setting that prevents the user from enabling power saver mode?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no policy in the Android Management API policy to prevent users from enabling power saver mode.